# Making HTTP request to my localhost on flutter not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, flutter, http-get

I am trying to get my data to show on my flutter app from a api (formatted in json) created by connecting mysql on node.js with express.

i am running this error in android studio console

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 
'List<dynamic>'
```

the api currently looks like this

```
{
    "error": false,
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "conner",
              "age": 24
            },
            {
              "name": "andrew",
              "age": 20
            }
         ],
         "message": "Todos list."
         }
```

I am using this tutorial and just replaced his value "title" with mine "name", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PRrdG163to

here is the code I'm running

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Map<String,dynamic> data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://10.1.0.109:8080/names"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );

    this.setState(() {
      data = JSON.decode(response.body);
    });
    print (data[1]["data"]);

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Listviews"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data["data"].length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Text(data[index]["data"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the structure of your JSON file  it's not the same as in the tutorial so try this

```
data["data"][1]["name"]
```

> NOTE :

change data from `list` to `var`  or `Map<String,dynamic>`

```
Map<String,dynamic> data;
```

after that you need to get the list length so in the itemCount change it to

```
itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data["data"].length,
```

[Full Example](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/ce8df52d2b044c6c0b14990d32b80e08)

[image]

Comment: but name needs to be a string doesn't it, ill get compiling errors otherwise

Comment: sorry i did i small typo in the code try the edited one

Comment: Yeah the argument says that i cant have a string but only an integer after, and if i do this print (data[1]["data","name"]);  it says too many positional arguements

Comment: ill try to just put "data"

Comment: yeah it wont work, im going to try to restructure my json file

Comment: see the edited answer i tried it and it works the problem was on the type of the data variable i didn't notice that its not a list

Comment: that didn't work as well when i put [name] or [data] getting this error---- The method '[]' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: []("data")

Comment: and if you are still with me every other time i hot reload i also get this error-------The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(375.0,
flutter: 812.0), devicePixelRatio: 3.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets:
flutter: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false)):

Comment: sorry again i updated my answer the second problem was on the list length

Comment: its saying the "getter length was called on null", im putting all my values as ["data"] right? if so im still running into problems

Comment: even with [this](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/ce8df52d2b044c6c0b14990d32b80e08)? if so the problem would be in the API it self. did you try to test it on the browser ?

Comment: Yeah i copied and pasted that i still run into the same problems, the problem seems be that when i pull it up on mobile browser it comes formatted raw and not parsed but on the web browser on computer it shows it in json format

Comment: i think your problem is in the result  JSON  its not the same as in the question